# Conditional Html attribute using razor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a situation where I want to display a button as being enabled or disabled depending on a property which has been set on the view model.

```
@if (Model.CanBeDeleted)
{
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> </span>
        Delete
    </button>
}
@if (!Model.CanBeDeleted)
{
    <button disabled="disabled" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> </span>
        Delete
    </button>
}
```

The code currently in my view, which can be seen above, does work.

However, I am looking for a way that I can wrap only the `disabled` attribute in the if statement rather than having a separate button element for each case.

Any suggestions for how I can do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use `@Html.Raw` to inject markup directly into elements

```html
<button @Html.Raw(Model.CanBeDeleted?"":"disabled='disabled'") 
        type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> </span> Delete
</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working in ASP.NET Core :(

Answer (score 40):

Try this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" disabled="@Model.CanBeDeleted">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> </span>
        Delete
</button>
```

Go ahead. Try it. You'll notice that when `@Model.CanBeDeleted`is false, the `disable` attribute is missing from the element. Conversely, when `@Model.CanBeDeleted` is true the `disable`element is present, and is set to `disable`

How does it work?

It's thanks to Razor's "conditional attributes" feature. if you assign a razor variable to an atribute in your `cshtml` (or `vbhtml`) it will behave like this:

1. If the variable or expression evaluates to null or false, it will ommit the attribute in the resulting html.
2. If the variable or expression evaluates to true it will output the attribute AND will assign it a value equal to the name of the attribute (e.g.: `disabled=disabled`, `checked=checked`... you get the idea)
3. If the variable or expression evaluates to a non-empty string it will assign it to the atribute as usual (e.g.: `class="@myvar"` => `class="the_value_of_myvar`")
4. If the variable or expression evaluates to an empty string, it will output the attribute but won't assign any value.

What I love about this sintax is that it greatly helps in keeping your razor views readable.

You can read more about it in this [article](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/conditional-attributes-in-razor-view-engine-and-asp.net-mvc-4)

Comment: I find this answer much cleaner given the OP's use case.

Comment: I applied the same mechanism for the `checked` attribute on a `checkbox`. Thanks for adding _"Go ahead. Try it."_, otherwise I may have discarded this solution up front!

Comment: if works for me  `<input asp-for="CompanyName" class="form-control" disabled=@Model.IsEdit />`

Comment: best answer for an issue that looked easy but gave me some trouble until i found this, thank you

Comment: Does not work if the attribute is preceded by "data-". For instance, if I set an attribute like data-test="@null" it is added to the html.

Answer (score 5):

```
<!button @(Model.CanBeDeleted?"":"disabled='disabled'") 
type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> </span> Delete
</!button>
```

You can Opt out individual elements from being evaluated as a [TagHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro) with !(Exclamation Point)

In its current form, Razor TagHelpers don't allow you to insert attributes by including the string literal of the attribute you want to insert.

Answer (score 0):

Do the check once and have the disabled property be determined by a temporary variable called enabled.

```
@code
    var enabled = "disabled='disabled'";
    if(Model.CanBeDeleted)
    enabled = "";
    end code
    <button Html.Raw(enabled) type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> </span>
            Delete
        </button>
```